# How to properly mock EntityManager.detach

Tags: unit-testing, spring-data-jpa, mockito

**Updated**

I could use some help with the proper way to mock EntityManager.detach() in Spring using Mockito.  I'm not sure what to put in the doAnswer block in the test.  Everything I've tried results in an NPE on the em.detach() call in the service impl.  The debugger shows that both em and existing are valid, non-null objects.  (Shared EntityManager proxy for target factory [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory#0 bean]).  Full NPE stack trace added.

Service class

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class MyEntityServiceImpl implements MyEntityService {
  private final MyDao dao;
  
  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager em;
  
  public MyEntityServiceImpl(MyDao dao) {
    super();
    this.dao = dao;
  }
  public MyDto update(MyDto dto) {
    // check preconditions for null and empty
    
    MyEntity existing = dao.findByBusinessKey(dto.getBusinessKey());
    if(existing == null) {
        throw new NotFoundException();
    }
    em.detach(existing) // NPE on this line during unit test.  
    
    // business logic
    
    MyEntity saved = dao.save(existing);
  }
```

Unit test

```
@SpringJUnitConfig()
class ServiceImplTest {
  @Autowired
  private MyEntityServiceImpl service;
  
  @MockBean
  private MyDao dao;
  
  @MockBean
  EntityManagerFactory emf;
  
  @MockBean
  EntityManager em;
  
  @Test
  public void givenValidEntity_whenUpdate_thenNoException() {
    MyDto existing = MyDto.builder.businessKey("valid business key").build();
    when(dao.findByBusinessKey(any(MyDto.class)).thenReturn(existing);
    doAnswer( invocation -> {
        // what goes in here??!?!?!
    }).when(em).detach(any(MyDto.class));
    
    assertDoesNotThrow(() -> {
        service.update(existing);
    });
  }
}
```

Stack Trace

```
    org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Unexpected exception thrown: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertDoesNotThrow.createAssertionFailedError(AssertDoesNotThrow.java:83)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertDoesNotThrow.assertDoesNotThrow(AssertDoesNotThrow.java:54)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertDoesNotThrow.assertDoesNotThrow(AssertDoesNotThrow.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertDoesNotThrow(Assertions.java:3060)
    at MyEntityServiceImpl.givenValidEntity_whenUpdate_thenNoException(MyEntityServiceImpl.java:126)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor$$Lambda$135/0x0000000075d4ab40.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall$$Lambda$136/0x0000000075b80880.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$$Lambda$335/0x0000000075f81e80.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor$$Lambda$452/0x0000000075ba46f0.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:206)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask$$Lambda$215/0x0000000075d4fad0.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask$$Lambda$214/0x0000000075bb9a70.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask$$Lambda$213/0x0000000075bb9600.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService$$Lambda$219/0x0000000075d52eb0.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask$$Lambda$215/0x0000000075d4fad0.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask$$Lambda$214/0x0000000075bb9a70.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask$$Lambda$213/0x0000000075bb9600.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService$$Lambda$219/0x0000000075d52eb0.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask$$Lambda$215/0x0000000075d4fad0.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask$$Lambda$214/0x0000000075bb9a70.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask$$Lambda$213/0x0000000075bb9600.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator$$Lambda$179/0x0000000075c7b430.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:559)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy45.detach(Unknown Source)
    at impl.MyEntityServiceImpl.update(MyEntityServiceImpl.java:107)
    at MyEntityServiceImpl.lambda$0(MyEntityServiceImpl.java:127)
    at MyEntityServiceImpl$$Lambda$463/0x00000000765fc660.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertDoesNotThrow.assertDoesNotThrow(AssertDoesNotThrow.java:50)
    ... 86 more
```

Comment: First thing if you are getting NPE at that line means - "em" is null. That means your mocked bean em is not injected.
Second thing you should use doNothing().when(em).detach()  - since it's a void method you want to mock

Comment: Lucia Thanks for reviewing!  I updated the question to show the full stack trace and that em is not null based on a debugging session.  Also switched to doNothing and continue to get an NPE on the same line.

Comment: So it's trying to create a new entityManager from the provided entitymanager factory at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator.  So you need to debug it and check what exactly is null at anagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311).

Comment: If it is just plain unit test why are you using spring test context.
Why cant you just run with plain mockitoJunitRunner and use @mock to the enityManager.
https://www.baeldung.com/java-spring-mockito-mock-mockbean

Comment: Thanks for the input.  Once I debugged into the detach call it was obvious that it was a real EntityManager not a mock.  I switched from @PersistenceContext to constructor injection and the test is green.  WRT switching away from Spring test context, there are other tests in the same class that need it.  I prefer not to create another test class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was the EntityManager was not being mocked.  I changed from @PersistenceContext to  constructor initialization and the test is green.

**Fixed Service class**

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class MyEntityServiceImpl implements MyEntityService {
  private final MyDao dao;
  
  private EntityManager em;
  
  public MyEntityServiceImpl(MyDao dao, EntityManager em) {
    super();
    this.dao = dao;
    this.em = em;
  }
  
  // other code unchanged from original question
}
```